# Opening next page after period of time | flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, future

i have a button which is rotating after click on it (code is shortened to be more readable).

**What is the problem ?**

When user clicks button, it rotates, ( *function `animation()` does that* ) and navigate to next page, but problem is when user clicks button few times before a full rotation, then after that 1000ms it opens a lot of `FriendsPageEditable` and he must to go back pressing navigation back button.

**What  i want :**

i want to this "extra sites" won't show up.

**Ways to resolve this problem which i can't implement bcs i dont know how:**

- Disable button after this first click to navigation.
- Disable it off for a period of time for example that 1000 ms.
- I guess stop using `Future.delayed` but i dont know what we could do later.

[image: app]

```
 bool buttonEnabled = true;

 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          animation();
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
          if (buttonEnabled) {
            buttonEnabled = true;
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const FriendsPageEditable()));
          } else {
            null;
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.settings,
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Malak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16231131/malak) try this:

```
bool buttonClicked = false;

 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          // Then check if the button has been clicked
          if(!buttonClicked)
            buttonClicked = true;
          else
            return;
          
          animation();
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), (){
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const FriendsPageEditable()));
            });
        buttonClicked = !buttonClicked;
        },
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.settings,
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Unfortunately, executing *onpressed* ends on ```return``` every time.

Comment: Yes, the initial value of buttonClicked needs to be false. :)